# Apache access log - requests to url that are not part of my site

Tags: apache-2.2

I am developing website to which only few people have access to.
Now I'm fairly new to server management but i did install apache and everything else by myself so most likely i made some errors in the process.

Today I have noticed that my website started to take a lot of time to load 5-20 seconds while usually it takes 1-2 secs at most. This doesnt happen due to my programming errors, I have double checked everything and page gets generated in under one second, but http requests takes for ever to load.

So i looked at the logs and error log was pretty much clean, but access log got me really worried, there is tons of GET requests from all kind of urls, just to name few:

```
"GET http://www.aromaconnection.org/2009/11/in-flanders-fields.html"
"GET http://losice.info/losicki-szpital-certyfikatem/"
"GET http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=http%3A%2F%2Fvk%2Ecom%2Fvideo36879733%5F166822918&b=11
```

Did i got hacked or something? If not why do i get all these requests and what could be causing these long load times?

**EDIT** I tried to change error log level to debug and this is what im starting to get:

`[info] server seems busy, (you may need to increase StartServers, or Min/MaxSpareServers), spawning 16 children, there are 0 idle, and 26 total children`

I guess here is my problem, but that still doesnt explain all those GET requests.

Comment: You omitted some important parts of the log entries. Please post some examples of complete log entries.

Comment: This is clearly the case of Proxy Abuse. Just follow the steps mentioned over here: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal to get scans. What I suspect in your case, is that your default virtual host serves your website. That means that any scan to the IP of your server ends up causing your app to do useless work.

I would create a default virtual host with just an empty index.html or a 404 or 403 error, and configuring the server such that your site only loads when going to `www.yourdomain.com`, and not to `http://1.2.3.4` (that being your address). Look at name based virual hosting in the Apache docs.